# JSONObject cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseGeoPoint

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

I am saving geopoint in the JsonObject using:

```
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jA=new JSONArray();

        if(lx.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "No location to upload now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            for(int uq=0;uq<lx.size();uq++){
                Double latit=lx.get(uq).getLatit();
                Double longit=lx.get(uq).getLongit();
                ParseGeoPoint pgPoint=new ParseGeoPoint(latit,longit);
                jA.put(pgPoint);


            }
            try {
                obj.put("locations",jA);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

After this I am sending this Jsonobject to parse cloud.

```
                po.put("historyfile", obj);
                po.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
```

Now I tried to get it back with this:

```
            JSONArray locations;
            ParseGeoPoint
            locations = obj.getJSONArray("locations");
            for (int yx = 0; yx < locations.length(); yx++) {
                pg =(ParseGeoPoint)locations.get(yx);

               //draw this geopoint on googlemap
            }
```

Firstly at the line:

```
             pg =(ParseGeoPoint)locations.get(yx);
```

I got error of type mismatch.When I typecasted this into parse object then it ran fine;But when I tried to run apk I got this error:

```
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseGeoPoint
```

Comment: May I ask you why you are saving a JSON object to Parse? `locations.get(yx)` is just a `JSONObject` when you get it back, not a `ParseGeoPoint`. You'll probably need to build one manually (or use a library), based on the fields of your `JSONObject`. Btw, the cast is performed at runtime, so that's why you can compile your code successfully.

Comment: but locations is a JSONArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try go to the parse.com data page and copy paste your JSONObject to jsonlint.com, then you will see exactly what `pg` looks like once saved inside a JSONObject. It is essentially a string value that can be treated as a JSONObject, but there is no way a String, or JSONObject for that matter can be cast directly to ParseGeoPoint. 
At best you can dive in an retrieve the lat/lon values:

```
JSONArray locations;
ParseGeoPoint
locations = obj.getJSONArray("locations");
for (int yx = 0; yx < locations.length(); yx++) {
    pg = locations.getJSONObject(yx);
    Double lat = pg.getDouble("latitude")
    Double lon = pg.getDouble("longitude")
    //draw this geopoint on googlemap
}
```

Now I havent tried to save a ParseGeoPoint as JSONObject the way you do, so not sure if the above is correct, just an example.

If you just need to be able to store and retrieve the location, then you could simply do:

```
...
for(int uq=0;uq<lx.size();uq++){
    Double latit=lx.get(uq).getLatit();
    Double longit=lx.get(uq).getLongit();
    JSONObject jsonPos = new JsonObject()
    json.put("lat", latit);
    json.put("lon", longit);
    jA.put(jsonPos);
}
...
```

And

```
JSONArray locations;
ParseGeoPoint
locations = obj.getJSONArray("locations");
for (int yx = 0; yx < locations.length(); yx++) {
    pg =locations.getJSONObject(yx);
    Double lat = pg.getDouble("lat")
    Double lon = pg.getDouble("lon")
    //draw this geopoint on googlemap
}
```